# In Prolog why does this query return this particular result

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel, prolog-assert

```
?- assert(p(a)),assert(p(b)),p(X).
X = a 
yes
```

Whats the effect of this query and why does it return this particular result?

Answer (score 2):

It is as if you queried the following source:

**input.pl:**

```
p(a).
p(b).
```

**?-** `p(X)`

```
X = a
yes
```

Comment: Addendum:  if you type, IIRC, ";" (or is it ","), you will continue the query and the answer ```X=b``` will be returned.